# Creating Dialog failed, Lint keeps complaining

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

I'm start using Android Studio since it's more supported. So I start using gradle too. Sadly, Lint prevents me to create Dialog. Either using DialogFragment or using AlertDialog directly, I still get complaints make my build always failed.

This is what I did:

```
cd ~/AndroidStudioProjects/TextEditor/app
gradle build
```

The lint gives me fatal error saying that `ValidFragment: Fragment not instantiatable`. While the description is `This fragment class should be public (id.web.michsan.texteditor.fragment.EditorFragment.6)`. I got no complaints from AndroidStudio IDE though.

It's actually a Dialog which ask user to save data before leaving current page and proceeding to another window.

```
public void endEditingSession(int nextActionCode, Bundle args) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_yes,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    UiAction nextAction = new UiAction() {
                        @Override
                        public void doIt(Context context) {
                            // Proceed to next action
                        }
                    };
                }
            });

    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_no,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // Nothing to do. Just proceed.
                }
            });

    builder.show();
}
```

What's going on with Android Lint? What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by doing `gradle clean build` instead of `gradle build`. OMG! I don't know if this is a gradle android bug or not.